# Drag'n'Drop Div return to a new final position

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm trying to create a drag and drop where I can move the item to a different position on the list and it will update the list in real-time, so if in the example bellow I move the div with the content `1` to the div with content `3` the div 2 and 3 will move up and the div with content 1 will be in the place of the third. So far no problem, I can drop it there and it is all correct.
The problem appears when I don't drop and move the div to a no dropable area and let it go, in this case, it will return to its original place where I first dragged it out from in the first position, however, I want it to return to its new position where the 3 used to be.

Example code: https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-night-phej3?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Start drag 1:
[image: Start drag 1]

Hover over 3, what makes 1 take its place
[image: Hover over 3, what makes 1 take its place]

Without stop dragging move out and drop
[image: Without stop drag move out and drop]

I want to make the div with 1 return to its new place following the line gree, instead, it is returning to its original place following the line red.

My React Code just for reference

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";

const initList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
function App() {
  const [list, setList] = useState(initList);
  const [draggedItem, setDraggedItem] = useState(null);

  function onDragStartHandle(e, index) {
    setDraggedItem(list[index]);
    e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = "move";
    e.dataTransfer.setData("text/html", e.target.parentNode);
    e.dataTransfer.setDragImage(e.target.parentNode, 20, 22);
  }

  function onDragOverHandle(e, index) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const draggedOverItem = list[index];

    if (draggedOverItem === draggedItem) {
      return;
    }

    const items = list.filter((item) => item !== draggedItem);
    items.splice(index, 0, draggedItem);
    setList(items);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <h3>Drag'n'Drop</h3>
        <ul>
          {list.map((item, index) => (
            <li
              key={index}
              onDragOver={(e) => onDragOverHandle(e, index)}
              className="item-style"
            >
              <div draggable onDragStart={(e) => onDragStartHandle(e, index)}>
                {item}
              </div>
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: I copy/pasted this into a codesandbox (sans App.css) and I am unable to reproduce. Perhaps I don't quite understand your repro steps (like, what is a "no draggable area"), or I have different behavior since I don't have *all* your code. Can you try sharing a codesandbox (or similar) that accurately reproduces the issue?

Comment: Thanks, @DrewReese I put the code in codesandbox as you suggested

Comment: Ok, thanks, I'm still unable to repro. I've tried dragging [1] to 3's position and drop and that seems to work, and I've also dragged [1] to 3's position *without* letting it go, and I can see underneath it the "tiles" all swap places and adjust, *then* continue dragging just about *anywhere* else and drop, and [1] appears to correctly stay in the new position. Maybe this is a browser issue? I'm on Chrome 83 MacOS 10.14.6. What are you repro'ing in?

Comment: @DrewReese thanks for your help, the problem is when you drag 1 to 3, without let it go drag anywhere far from the list and let it go, it will return to the original position, where now is the number 2  (just the animation) it should animate the return to the position 3 where it is now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, took a while to really look into this and best I could come up with is when you drag over an element you were going ahead and updating the state, but if the user abandons the drop the element "snaps" back to where it originated from and ***not*** the last placed it hovered. I spent some time looking at the [Drag and Drop API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API) and nothing really jumped out as being able to modify this behavior "mid-flight".

What I think is *technically* more correct behavior for abandoned drops, i.e. the user doesn't drop the element in the list, is for the list to maintain the state it had previously from *before* the drag was initiated.

Here's a solution that adds an additional piece of state to mutate *during* a drag event, and if the drop is successful then that temp state is committed to the "real" list state, and if unsuccessful reverts back to the existing list state (it just remains unchanged).

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";

const initList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

function App() {
  const [list, setList] = useState(initList);
  const [dragList, setDragList] = useState(null);
  const [draggedItem, setDraggedItem] = useState(null);

  /**
   * On drag start
   * Initialize the temporary item being dragged and drag list.
   */
  const onDragStartHandle = index => e => {
    setDraggedItem(list[index]);
    setDragList(list);
    e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = "move";
    e.dataTransfer.setData("text/html", e.target.parentNode);
    e.dataTransfer.setDragImage(e.target.parentNode, 20, 22);
  };

  /**
   * On drag end
   * Save updated drag list to list and nullify temporary values.
   */
  const onDragEndHandle = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setList(dragList);
    setDragList(null);
    setDraggedItem(null);
  };

  /**
   * On drag leave
   * Item wasn't dropped so reset temporary drag list
   */
  const onDragLeaveHandle = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setDragList(list);
  };

  /**
   * On drag over
   * If dragging over another item update the drag list with new position
   */
  const onDragOverHandle = index => e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const draggedOverItem = dragList[index];

    if (draggedOverItem === draggedItem) {
      return;
    }

    const items = dragList.filter(item => item !== draggedItem);
    items.splice(index, 0, draggedItem);
    setDragList(items);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <h3>Drag'n'Drop</h3>
        <ul>
          {(draggedItem ? dragList : list).map((item, index) => (
            <li key={index} className="item-style">
              <div
                draggable
                onDragOver={onDragOverHandle(index)} // Moved *
                onDragLeave={onDragLeaveHandle}
                onDragEnd={onDragEndHandle}
                onDragStart={onDragStartHandle(index)}
              >
                {item}
              </div>
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

***** Moved from `li` element to `div` to keep all events originating from the same element. Having the `onDragOver` event listener on the list item was causing a weird issue where sometimes the UI would get "stuck" in the semi-hovered state.

[image: Edit drag-n-drop list]